# Calculate distances in multi-dimensional matrix

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

I wrote this code to calculate the distance. But getting error of `ValueError: math domain error`.

```
import math

a=[[5, 10],
   [16, 23]]

b=[[6, 1], [21, 2]]

dL=[]
dist=[]
k=0
h=1
for i in range(len(a)):
    dL=[]
    for j in range(len(a)):
        d=math.sqrt((a[i][k]-b[j][k])^2 + (a[i][h]-b[j][h])^2)
        dL.append(d)
    dist.append(dL)
```

In the iterations, `d` should be:

```
i=0, j=0: d=sqrt((5-6)^2+(10-1)^2)
i=0, j=1: d=sqrt((5-21)^2+(10-2)^2)
i=1, j=0: d=sqrt((16-6)^2+(23-1)^2)
i=1, j=1: d=sqrt((16-21)^2+(23-2)^2)
```

Comment: `^2` doesn't square, it XORs.

Comment: Use `x ** y` to raise `x` to the `y`th power.

Comment: How can I round d to 4 decimal places in the same line when i calculate d

Comment: You should also consider using the built-in [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) function as using it would likely be faster.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `len(a)` is 2, and FOR count since 0, so, ask for the 3rd element in the array, you must do 
 `for i in range(len(a) - 1):`

Comment: `range(len(a))` will only generates values from `0` to `len(a)-1` inclusive, so what you're suggesting is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

sqrt gives that error when you try to use it with a negative number. sqrt(-16) gives that error because the result is a complex number.

```
from math import sqrt
a=[[5, 10], [16, 23]]


b=[[6, 1], [21, 2]]

dL=[]
dist=[]
k=0
h=1
for i in range(len(a)):
    dL=[]
    for j in range(len(a)):
        temp1 = (a[i][k]-b[j][k]) ** 2
        temp2 = (a[i][h]-b[j][h]) ** 2
        temp = temp1 + temp2
        if temp > 0:
            d = sqrt(temp)

        dL.append(d)
    dist.append(dL)
```

Comment: The problem, which your answer doesn't solve, lies in the OP's use of `^` instead of `**`, which is already explained in the comments.

Comment: Yeah i to agree but there is another problem in squareroot  function if we use sqrt for negative number returns in complex number @ThierryLathuille

Comment: Squares are positive.

Answer (score 0):

As @not_a_robot mentioned in their comment, the exponentiation operator in Python is `**` not `^` as it is in (many) other programming languages. You can fix your by simply replacing them.

```
import math

a= [[ 5, 10],
    [16, 23]]
b= [[ 6,  1],
    [21,  2]]

dL=[]
dist=[]
k=0
h=1
for i in range(len(a)):
    dL=[]
    for j in range(len(a)):
        d = math.sqrt((a[i][k]-b[j][k])**2 + (a[i][h]-b[j][h])**2)
        dL.append(d)
    dist.append(dL)
```

As I mentioned in a comment, it would be better to use `math.hypot()` for this as it will give you the same results more quickly and is easier to read (and write):

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    dL=[]
    for j in range(len(a)):
        d = math.hypot(a[i][k]-b[j][k], a[i][h]-b[j][h])
        dL.append(d)
    dist.append(dL)
```